How do I modify this flow formula?
So, in this flow formula I need two things to happen:

Country is a lookup field, and I want the formula to auto populate my record name with the first 3 letters of whatever country is picked in that Country field. Those letters also need to be capitalized.
When the record saves, there are spaces instead of dashes in the concatenation.

{!$Record.Name} != UPPER(LEFT({!$Record.Country__r.Name}, 3)) + " " + 
CASE({!$Record.Registration_Type__c},
    "Re-Registration", "RR",
    "First Time", "FT",
    "RR"
) + " " + TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))

The problem:

Whenever I click 'Save' on my record, say Mexico is chosen in my Country lookup field, the record name will save as 'A05 - RR - 2024'
I have no idea why it is choosing 'A05' every time I save the record, or why there are dashes and not spaces.

What I want to happen:

When I click 'Save' to save a new record I want to have the name read as 'MEX RR 2024' (this is if Mexico is chosen, if Honduras was chosen it would be 'HON RR 2024').


This flow formula looks like it gives you a boolean (true/false) as a result. It's probably being used as an entry criteria or in a decision node, rather than being part of a field update action. You should be looking for the formulas/values that are used in the field update action(s).

Just following up on Derek's comment and answer, 'A05' will be the object prefix to the Id of the related Country record. I would assume the current formula is getting the first three characters from the Lookup field on the Account (which stores an ID), rather than the Name of the record as per Derek's formula in his answer. Because the prefix will be consistent across all the records, you'd always get the same result (and not one that is useful to a user either!).

Seems like your formula should be
UPPER(LEFT({!$Record.Country__r.Name}, 3)) + " - " +  /* 1st 3 chars country name */
CASE({!$Record.Registration_Type__c},
    "Re-Registration", "RR",
    "First Time", "FT",
    "RR"
) + " - " + TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))


Thank you guys! The next challenge for this, is at the end I want '00000001' to be appended at the end of the auto population. Any advice on that would be appreciated, but I will also be taking a crack at it.

All I did for the final part was create an autonumber field and reference it in my flow formula, concatenating it at the end. Thanks again everyone for the help.
